# Use Sqoop on different user?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am having two users "ashish" and "ashuser". Hadoop is installed on "ashuser".

But I mistakenly installed Sqoop on "ashish" user.

So whenever I tried to check Sqoop version in "ashuser", I am getting an error "Command Not Found".

I tried giving ownership to Sqoop folder for "ashuser".

Is there any possibility that I can use Sqoop on "ashuser"?

Comment: You can try using `sudo` command. Using sudo Sqoop command will be    `sudo HADOOP_USER_NAME=desiredUser sqoop import <generic args>`

Comment: why not just `export PATH` to include the sqoop command?